# Find natural number solutions to $x^2-2y^2=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

One solution I found is $x=2, y=1$. But my question is:

Is this the only natural solution?

Comment: Which solution? You have posted a term only.

Comment: @callculous I am very sorry for the typo!

Comment: How 'bout $100-98$?

Comment: @Barry Cipra can you tell me how you calculated those values?

Comment: The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ is a unique factorization domain.  Therefore, all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2-2y^2=2$ are of the form $$x+\sqrt{2}\,y=\pm(2+\sqrt{2})\,(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n}\,,$$ where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Partly by trial and error, but informed by decades of experience doing number theory. Please provide some context for your question, such as how you came across this problem and what you've done beyond finding the small solution you mentioned.

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Transformations_.

Comment: BTW, my previous comment may have across as more grandiose than I had intended. I didn't mean to suggest it takes decades to get good at solving simple problems in elementary number theory, but only that it took me that long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(a,b)$ is a solution of the *[negative Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell_equation)* $x^2-2y^2=-1$ (many $x$ values of solutions are listed at [OEIS A02315](https://oeis.org/search?q=A02315&language=english&go=Search)).  Then a solution of $x^2-2y^2=2$ can be obtained as below:

$$a^2-2b^2=-1$$

$$-2a^2+4b^2=2$$

$$(2b)^2-2a^2=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $(x,y)$ is a solution, then so is $(3x+4y, 2x+3y)$.

Comment: Nice observation, how did arrive to it?

Comment: *How did you arrive to it?

Comment: @SujalMotagi:  cf. the above comment by Batominovski and multiply $x+y\sqrt2$ by $(1+\sqrt2)^2=3+2\sqrt2$

Comment: From the theory of Pell-type equations.

Answer (score 0):

With an equation of the form $x^2-Dy^2=N$, whenever $(x, y)$ is a solution, $(ax+by, cx+dy)$ is a solution for some $a, b, c, d$ which depend on the coefficients of the original equation but not on $x$ or $y$. Here's one way to find those coefficients $a, b, c, d$ in the OP's case:

\begin{align*}
(ax+by)^2-2(cx+dy)^2 &= 2\\
\implies (a^2-2c^2)x^2+2(ab-2cd)xy+(b^2-2d^2)y^2 &= 2\\
\implies a^2-2c^2 &= 1;\\
ab &= 2cd;\\
b^2-2d^2 &= -2.
\end{align*}
So if you can find a solution to $a^2-2c^2 = 1$, you may take $d=a$ and $b=2c$. $a=3, b=2$ works, so we get the recurrence which Robert Israel pointed out.

More generally, if the original equation is $x^2-Dy^2=N$,
\begin{align*}
(ax+by)^2-D(cx+dy)^2 &= N\\
\implies (a^2-Dc^2)x^2+2(ab-Dcd)xy+(b^2-Dd^2)y^2 &= N\\
\implies a^2-Dc^2 &= 1;\\
ab &= Dcd;\\
b^2-Dd^2 &= -D\\
\implies d^2-\frac{b^2}{D} &= 1\\
\implies d^2-D\Big(\frac{b}{D}\Big)^2&=1
\end{align*}
So again, if you can find a solution to $a^2-2c^2 = 1$, you may take $d=a$ and $b=Dc$.